# Реализация иерархии одинаковых классов C#

Tags: c#, классы

Здравствуйте, прошу помочь мне разработать логику классов.
Дело в том, что мне нужно построить правильную иерархию изделий (состав одного изделия). Входные данные выглядят примерно таким образом:

- 1 Машина

  - 1.1 Двигатель

    - 1.1.1 Поршень
    - 1.1.2 Втулка
  - 1.2 Карбюратор

    - 1.2.1 Болт

      - 1.2.1.1 Винт
  - 1.3 Руль

Соответственно, из чего состоит изделие мне заранее неизвестно (классы как-то должны создаваться динамически).

Подразумевается, что классы изделий будут с одинаковыми полями, то есть, как мне кажется, иерархия одинаковых классов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, лаконичную реализацию на .Net 4.5 либо куда мне копать для разработки такой иерархии.

Что касаемо необходимых полей, то это точно "Рабочий, создающий деталь" и "время его работы"

Comment: Одинаковые классы - это один и тот же класс. То есть, вы конечно, можете, объявить несколько классов с идентичной структурой - но с точки зрения компилятора это всё равно будет один и тот же класс (утиная типизация, вот это всё). Вы имеете в виду категории изделий, может быть?

Comment: изделия везде одинаковые (думаю, класс один и тот же), но мне как-то нужно реализовать зависимость от родительского класса к дочерним, то есть везде один и тот же класс, но с иерархией.

Comment: Тут у вас не иерархия/наследование (is), а композиция/агрегация (has).

Comment: Очень советую вам ненадолго отвлечься от решения конкретных задач и почитать какие-нибудь книжки по ООП (хотя бы Гради Буча, или что-то может новое хорошее есть), а потом уж вернуться к собственно программированию.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем вопросе налицо непонимание самого термина [класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x9afc042.aspx). Боюсь, вам следует начать с изучения основ ООП (почитайте, для начала, [статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), затем [приступить к изучению C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/67ef8sbd.aspx).

---

Теперь давайте попробуем разобраться с вашим вопросом. Что вы имели в виду? Если вы всё же хотите выстроить иерархию классов, то вы хотите сделать это неверно. Очевидно, что если класс "Втулка" - это уточнение класса "Автомобиль", то это, мягко говоря, некорректно. То есть, программе, конечно, всё равно, но с точки зрения человека это просто не имеет смысла. Как устроена иерархия коассов? Так же, как в жизни! Например, у вас есть класс "Автомобиль", производным классом от которого является "Москвич". Москвич наследует от Автомобиля все его атрибуты, но имеет и свои, уникальные (ну, не знаю, метод "Навонять в салоне бензином АИ-76"). От Москвича можно произвести ещё один класс - "Москвич-412", который так же является Москвичём (и, соответственно, автомобилем), но имеет ещё ряд дополнений, например моднейший дизайн и богатырский рык.

Таким образом, иерархия классов - это дерево **уточнений**. Понятие "Втулка", как вы, надеюсь, понимаете, никак не может уточнить понятие "Автомобиль". Подробнее про классы почитайте по ссылкам, которые я привёл выше.

---

Но, возможно, я вас неверно понял, и вам нужен какой-нибудь журнал производства, который вы видите организованным в виде дерева? Например, есть конкретные втулка и поршень, которые имеют время производства, которое, в свою очередь, влияет на вермя производства двигателя, которое влияет на время производства автомобиля?

Тут возможны различные варианты реализации. Например, у вас может быть класс "Продукт":

```
public class Product
{
  public float ProductionTime;
  public string Worker;
}
```

На основе продукта можно описать каждую деталь, а так же автомобиль. При этом, обратите внимание, все эти классы не будут наследовать от автомобиля (например), все они будут производными от продукта.

При этом класс "Двигатель" будет содержать поля "Втулка" и "Поршень", и иметь свой метод подсчёта вермени производства.

Класс "Автомобиль" - содержать поля "Двигатель", "Карбюратор" и "Руль", и т.д.

Код не привожу, поскольку, откровенно говоря, не вижу в этом особого смысла. Не обижайтесь, но на мой взгляд, решать эту задачу вам рано - см. начало ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я попросту не знаю практической реализации такой задачи.  Вот, видимо, по ошибке и спросил про иерархию классов. А таки классы я знаю. Всё сводится к тому, чтобы выстраивать иерархические связи от изделия к его составляющим. Как это реализуется на практике - я не нашёл примеров. Ибо какова иерархия состава изделия мне заранее неизвестна.

Comment: @astral - вам определённо подойдёт паттерн [Компоновщик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Компоновщик_(шаблон_проектирования)).